# render($content) puts comment form above markup - why?

Tags: 7, theming, comments

In my node--blog.tpl.php file, I have the following code:

```
<?php if ($teaser):?>
    <!-- Do some stuff -->
<?php else:?>
    <!-- A little HTML -->
    <?php print render($content);?>
<?php endif;?>
```

When I load up a blog page, the comments form is actually above the content.  This isn't some CSS quirk - it's above the content in the HTML structure.

How have I managed that, then?  Can anyone suggest a way to ensure the comments form appears in its rightful place, below the content?

Answer (score 2):

There is a **show weights** link in Drupal 7.14. If you go to Comment Fields in your content type /admin/structure/types/manage/.

I set the weight, and comments still show above the body.

Answer (score 1):

Just try to check weight of `$content` elements. it seems that comments element has low weight number.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this happen before with CCK forms.

If you have javascript enabled, it likes to reorder the weights of the fields with the drag-drop interface, and many of the hidden items don't appear in the selection.

The only way I found to fix the weight problem was to manually reassign the weights, which requires that you disable JS in your browser so the drag-drop interface goes away in favor of actual text boxes to enter the weight values.